# Flutter/Firebase error only returning unknown error type

Tags: flutter, firebase

I'm trying to error handle in flutter (on the web) with firebase. I'm using try-catch to error handle known erros. However, whenever I'm testing, firebase keeps on returning an error with the class `unknown` even though I should be getting specific ones like `'user-not-found'` or `'wrong-password'`. Anyone know what's wrong?

Entire code:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../firebase_options.dart';

class LoginView extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginView({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginView> createState() => _LoginViewState();
}

class _LoginViewState extends State<LoginView> {
  late final TextEditingController _email;
  late final TextEditingController _password;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _email = TextEditingController();
    _password = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _email.dispose();
    _password.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Login'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: Firebase.initializeApp(
          options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
        ),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.done:
              return Column(
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    controller: _email,
                    enableSuggestions: false,
                    autocorrect: false,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Enter your email',
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: _password,
                    obscureText: true,
                    enableSuggestions: false,
                    autocorrect: false,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Enter your password',
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      final email = _email.text;
                      final password = _password.text;
                      try {
                        final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                          email: email,
                          password: password,
                        );
                        print(userCredential);
                      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                        if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
                          print('user not found');
                        } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
                          print('wrong password');
                        } else {
                          print(e.code);
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    child: const Text('Login'),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            default:
              return const Text('Loading...');
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Specific code block that's not working:

```
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      final email = _email.text;
                      final password = _password.text;
                      try {
                        final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                          email: email,
                          password: password,
                        );
                        print(userCredential);
                      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                        if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
                          print('user not found');
                        } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
                          print('wrong password');
                        } else {
                          print(e.code);
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    child: const Text('Login'),
                  )
```

Output when I try handling a `user-not-found` or `wrong-password` error:

`unknown`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your flutter and dart version used for this project.You need to downgrade. There is open question to this and user fix by downgrading the version.

https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10966

Comment: Yeah it's a Flutter issue. Gotta downgrade until they patch it up.

Answer (score 0):

I used **e.message** instead of **e.code**.

Even though it's not that nice, but at least i'm able to get rid of the unknown.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by other users, it is a well-known issue right now. I see you are following Vandad Nahavandipoor´s exceptional course. This issue wont stop you from continuing with it. Case you need it, there is a temporary fix (regex) in the link given by Ankit Tale answer.